# How do I use pytest with Bazel?

Tags: python, pytest, bazel

I have a `my_module.py` file that implements `my_module` and a file `test_my_module.py` that does `import my_module` and runs some tests written with [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html) on it.

Normally I run the tests by `cd`ing into the directory that contains these two files and then doing

```
pytest
```

Now I want to use Bazel. I've added `my_module.py` as a `py_binary` but I don't know what the right way to invoke my tests is.

Comment: I opened a feature request https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/issues/240

Comment: A draft PR to support pytest: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/pull/464

Answer (score 11):

To create a reusable code that doesn't need to add a call to `pytest` at the end of every python file with tests. You can create a `py_test` rule to call a wrapper / runner of `pytest` and keeping all arguments. Then create a macro around the py_test. I explain the detailed solution in [Experimentations on Bazel: Python (3), linter & pytest](https://dev.to/davidb31/experimentations-on-bazel-python-3-linter-pytest-49oh), with link to source code.

Create the python tool (wrap the call to pytest, or only pylint) in `tools/pytest/pytest_wrapper.py`

```py
import sys
import pytest

# if using 'bazel test ...'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(pytest.main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Create the macro in `tools/pytest/defs.bzl`

```py
"""Wrap pytest"""

load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_test")
load("@my_python_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

def pytest_test(name, srcs, deps = [], args = [], data = [], **kwargs):
    """
        Call pytest
    """
    py_test(
        name = name,
        srcs = [
            "//tools/pytest:pytest_wrapper.py",
        ] + srcs,
        main = "//tools/pytest:pytest_wrapper.py",
        args = [
            "--capture=no",
            "--black",
            "--pylint",
            "--pylint-rcfile=$(location //tools/pytest:.pylintrc)",
            # "--mypy",
        ] + args + ["$(location :%s)" % x for x in srcs],
        python_version = "PY3",
        srcs_version = "PY3",
        deps = deps + [
            requirement("pytest"),
            requirement("pytest-black"),
            requirement("pytest-pylint"),
            # requirement("pytest-mypy"),
        ],
        data = [
            "//tools/pytest:.pylintrc",
        ] + data,
        **kwargs
    )
```

expose some resources from `tools/pytest/BUILD.bazel`

```py
exports_files([
    "pytest_wrapper.py",
    ".pylintrc",
])
```

Call it from your package `BUILD.bazel`

```py
load("//tools/pytest:defs.bzl", "pytest_test")
...

pytest_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
    deps = [
        ...
    ],
)
```

then calling `bazel test //...` means that `pylint`, `pytest` and `black` are all part of the test flow.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following code to `test_my_module.py` and mark the test script as a `py_test` instead of `py_binary` in your `BUILD` file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pytest
    raise SystemExit(pytest.main([__file__]))
```

Then you can run your tests with `bazel test test_my_module`

Comment: having to do what pytest does not require to satisfy bazel this way is a PITA and i think an unnecessary burden

Comment: Replacing `[__file__]` with `sys.argv` allows custom pytest options added with `pytest_addoption` to be forwarded.

Comment: While this answered the question, I struggled with other issues while migrating from python's pytest to bazel's py_test.  I captured those issues in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71085485/4548096

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bunch of the suggestions here have been packaged up into https://github.com/caseyduquettesc/rules_python_pytest now.

```
load("@rules_python_pytest//python_pytest:defs.bzl", "py_pytest_test")

py_pytest_test(
    name = "test_w_pytest",
    size = "small",
    srcs = ["test.py"],
    deps = [
      # TODO Add this for the user
      requirement("pytest"),
    ],
)
```

**Edit:** I'm the author of the above repository

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @David Bernard, who wrote his answer in an awesome series of blog posts BTW, there is a curve-ball there with pytest + bazel + Windows...

Long story short, you'll need to add `legacy_create_init = 0` to the `py_test` rule call.

This is a workaround a "feature" where bazel will create `__init__.py` files in the sandbox, even when none were present in your repo https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using protocol buffers, then there are some additional things you need to set. See https://github.com/aignas/bazel_pytest_proto for an excellent writeup. Essentially, Bazel `py_proto_library` and `pytest` test discovery don't play nice when it comes to imports and the `PYTHONPATH`.

```
# //tools/bazel/pytest/defs.bzl

load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", _py_test = "py_test")
load("@pip//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

def py_test(name, srcs, deps=[], args=[], **kwargs):
    _py_test(
        name = name,
        main = "//tools/bazel/pytest:main.py",
        srcs = srcs + ["//tools/bazel/pytest:main.py"],
        deps = deps + [requirement("pytest")],
        args = args + ["--import-mode=importlib"] + ["$(location :%s)" % s for s in srcs],
        **kwargs,
    )
```

```
# //tools/bazel/pytest/main.py

import sys
import pytest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(pytest.main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

```
# //tools/bazel/pytest/BUILD

exports_files([
    "main.py"
])
```