# How to migrate pytest to bazel py_test?

Tags: pytest, bazel

I want to convert our integration pytests over to bazel, but it doesn't seem to actually run nor produce the junitxml output I'm expecting:

```yaml
ARGS = [
    "--verbose",
    "--json-report",
    "--junit-xml=junit.xml",
]

py_test(
    name = "test_something",
    srcs = ["test_something.py"],
    args = ARGS,
    tags = [
        "yourit",
    ],
    deps = [
        requirement("pytest"),
        requirement("pytest-json-report"),
        ":lib",
    ],
)
```

There is a similar question here: [How do I use pytest with bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326587/how-do-i-use-pytest-with-bazel).  But it didn't cover the multitude of issues I ran into.

Answer (score 3):

So there were multiple things to address in order to make bazel's py_test work with pytest.

1. Of course you need the pytest dependency `requirement("pytest")` added.
2. The pytest files require a hook being added (note that the args are passed as well `sys.argv[1:]`, so py_test args can be passed on to the pytest file):

   ```py
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      sys.exit(pytest.main(\[__file__\] + sys.argv\[1:\]))
   ```
3. Since our pytests are trying to access the host network, we need to tell bazel to allow network traffic outside the sandbox by adding a `requires-network` tag.
4. The host network is local, so we need to make sure the test runs locally by adding the `local` tag.
5. Bazel py_test will create junitxml under bazel-testlogs, but it only shows if py_test rule passed or failed.  To get more granular junitxml results, we need to tell pytest how to overwrite bazel's py_test results using `XML_OUTPUT_FILE` environment variable. Note the `$$` is needed to prevent variable expansion. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/test-encyclopedia.html and https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/test/test-setup.sh#L67 for more info.
6. Attempts to write json report output to bazel-testlogs using `TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR` environment variable didn't work.  The report is still written, but inside bazel-out.  There might be a way to scoop up those files, but solving that problem was not a priority.
7. Note that the `ARGS` is used to keep it DRY (don't repeat yourself).  We use the same arguments across multiple `py_test` rules.

So the BUILD now looks like this:

```yaml
ARGS = [
    "--verbose",
    "--json-report",
    "--junit-xml=$$XML_OUTPUT_FILE",
]

py_test(
    name = "test_something",
    srcs = ["test_something.py"],
    args = ARGS,
    tags = [
        "local",
        "requires-network",
        "yourit",
    ],
    deps = [
        requirement("pytest"),
        requirement("pytest-json-report"),
        ":lib",
    ],
)
```